# Excel VBA xlPasteFormulas paste different value

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Below VBA code paste different value from copied one.

For example: below code copy Cells(11,13).Formula `"=SUM(M12:M13)"` to `Cells(11,14).Formula`, After copy and `xlPasteFormulas` paste to `Cells(11,14). Cells(11,14)` Formula becomes to `"=SUM(N12:N13)` .Does anybody know why? But the result is expected.

```
For x = A_OFFSET_MARKETVALUE To A_OFFSET_CURRENT
    Cells(nLevel1Position, iColumn).Select
    Selection.Copy

    Cells(nLevel1Position, iColumn + x).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Next x
```

I need optimized above code to below code. But below code give me same formular value which is not as expected. How should  optimize above code but still have same result as original code.

```
Cells(nLevel1Position, iColumn + x).Formula = Cells(nLevel1Position, iColumn).Formula
```

Comment: Your optimized code should do the Job for you.

Comment: I tried in My system, and it is doing the correct job of copying the exact formula.

Comment: Original code paste different result which is expected. I need optimize original code still keep different result after paste.

Comment: I think the issue is that `Cells(nLevel1Position, iColumn + x).Formula = Cells(nLevel1Position, iColumn).Formula` keeps the formula as it is (i.e. `=SUM(M12:M13)` is copied in the same form as displayed in cell M11). I suspect what OP wants to achieve is to have the cell references shifted (cell N11 would be equal to `=SUM(N12:N13)`).

Comment: @JustynaMK Yes, you  are right. So could you please give me optimize code for the original code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To 'streamline' this:

```
Range("M11:N11").Formula = "=SUM(M12:M13)"
```

Or:

```
Range("M11:N11").Formula = Range("M11").Formula
```

With this behaviour Excel "knows" you want to change the formulas referenced cells. So make use of that inbuild intelligence!

And in your own code, you don't need to use an iteration (since you want to offset it to column N), you can suffice with a change of above:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Change accordingly
    .Range(.Cells(nLevel1Position, iColumn), .Cells(nLevel1Position, iColumn + A_OFFSET_CURRENT)).Formula = .Cells(nLevel1Position, iColumn).Formula
End With
```

And in the last case, where you do need to offset from column M ( or in your code, `iColumn`) make use of `FormulaR1C1` instead of `.Formula`.

Like so:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    .Range(.Cells(nLevel1Position, iColumn + A_OFFSET_MARKETVALUE), .Cells(nLevel1Position, iColumn + A_OFFSET_CURRENT)).Formula = .Cells(nLevel1Position, iColumn).FormulaR1C1
End With
```

In all cases there is no iteration + added benefit there is not values pasted to Excel's clipboard, which should benefit your efficiency.

In case you do need the source's format, try:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    .Cells(nLevel1Position, iColumn).Copy
    .Range(.Cells(nLevel1Position, iColumn + A_OFFSET_MARKETVALUE), .Cells(nLevel1Position, iColumn + A_OFFSET_CURRENT)).PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormats)
    .Range(.Cells(nLevel1Position, iColumn + A_OFFSET_MARKETVALUE), .Cells(nLevel1Position, iColumn + A_OFFSET_CURRENT)).Formula = .Cells(nLevel1Position, iColumn).FormulaR1C1
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End With
```

Comment: thanks for provide solution. Unfortunately, they are not working as expected. Sorry for that. What I can do?

Comment: What does not work? Do you get an error? I tried it at my excel and it works just fine.

Comment: Acturally, your solution does work. With in debugging mode, after paste the value result are same as original code. But after I run entire report the cells value is not same with original result. Do I need set it to manual calculate or auto calculate? Is this cause the final result not same?

Comment: @DeepinDevelopment it's hard to understand both how your data looks plus what your situation is. Best is to update your question to make it more understandable. It's hard to help you without.

Comment: I do not understand why your solution 1 is not like below. But at least your solution is correct, even final result still not same as original one. .Range(.Cells(nLevel1Position, iColumn + A_OFFSET_MARKETVALUE), .Cells(nLevel1Position, iColumn + A_OFFSET_CURRENT)).Formula = .Cells(nLevel1Position, iColumn).Formula

Comment: @DeepinDevelopment at the end, try .FormulaR1C1 instead of .Formula

Comment: yes after add .FormulaR1C1 , the result is correct. The final result still not correct, I guess I also need copy and paste Cells Format. Do you know the optimized way to copy and paste Cells Format base on our code? Thanks you very much!

Comment: @DeepinDevelopment, try the code i just added in the answer

Comment: @DeepinDevelopment, I'm glad it's sorted. Please consider to upvote/accept the answer as a token of your appreciation.

Comment: Sure I will mark you answe as correct after few days because I may still need    ask you something else. You are EXCEL VBA EXPERT !!! MANY THANKS!!!

Comment: @I'm definately not an expert. Also, if your current question is answered, you should mark it as answered. New questions can be raised through this website and if I see them I'll make sure to answer them if I know the answers. That's how this website works.

Comment: Is it a possible way to transfer range (value and formula and format together) between two different sheets but Not using copy paste?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the previous answer, **do not use** `selection`.  There are many ways that you can mess up the script, e.g. clicking elsewhere.  instead, directly call the method `Copy` and `PasteSpecial`:

```
Cells(nLevel1Position, iColumn).Select
Selection.Copy

Cells(nLevel1Position, iColumn + x).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

can be changed to

```
Cells(nLevel1Position, iColumn).Copy

Cells(nLevel1Position, iColumn + x).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to shift cell references, then try the following code:

```
Cells(nLevel1Position, iColumn).Copy Cells(nLevel1Position, iColumn + x)
```

Comment: I am try your code, will let you know the  result. many thanks.

Comment: There is no need for iteration to shift cell references :)

Comment: @Justyna Unfortunately, the result is not correct. Do you need I provide debug values?

Comment: Yes please; might be even worth pasting a screenshot of your spreadsheet so that we can replicate it on our side and test it. In the meantime take a look at @JvdV solution, this one could also work.